# Как моментально получить уведомление о новом email письме на C#?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Как моментально получить уведомление о новом email письме на C#?

Comment: Что значит "моментально"?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну есть ли способ уведомления?или тогда каждые Х секунд запросы делать- то как это реализовать?

Comment: Про способ уведомления - я такого не знаю. Про периодическую проверку - очевидно, нужен таймер.

Comment: прикрутите imap, например через https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit - там вроде бы есть эвенты на новые письма